# Is Linux Kernel a process or a thread or some passive stuff that handle the requests come from application?

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, operating-system, kernel

It seems linux kernel running a process. But I read some answer that says linux kernel is neither process or thread. So I hope someone can explain this concept.

Comment: dup of: http://superuser.com/questions/197168/is-kernel-a-process

Answer (score 0):

Linux kernel is a program. It has lots of kernel threads. And has the code to schedule these threads and user space processes. And has device driver to control hardware, has interrupt handler code.

Comment: I think you need check more books.